# Max-Min values of $f(x,y) = x^3+y^3-6x^2-y-1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

I am asked to find the extrema of the function

$$f(x,y) =  x^3+y^3-6x^2-y-1$$

I understand that we have to equal the partial derivatives to zero, which means

$$
f_x = 3x^2-12x = 0\\
f_y = 3y^2-1 = 0\\
$$

which would give me

$$x = 0\\x = 4\\y = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\\y = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

but how may I find the "pairs" of coordinates of the possible extreme values? Should I make the four possible combinations of the $x$ and $y$ values for $4$ different points?

Comment: You have a local maximun at $(0,\frac{-\sqrt 3}{3})$ and a local minimun at $(4,\frac{\sqrt 3}{3})$

Comment: @Piquito ok how did you come to that conclusion? Did you use all of the combinations for the points (4 total)?

Comment: Read the answer of David. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've found the set of 4 critical points that make the partial derivatives of the function 0. Now you need to determine whether these are local maxes or mins or nothing. You can use 2nd derivatives to determine this.

To find local maxima and minimum, you can look at the Hessian, the second derivative matrix, which in this case is:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 6x-12 & 0\\ 0 & 6y \end{pmatrix}$$
If this is positive definite, then you've found a local min. If its negative definite, you've found a local max. You've found 4 critical points, and the matrix is negative definite at $(0,-\sqrt{3}/{3})$, and positive definite at $(4,\sqrt{3}/{3})$, so these are a local max and min respectively.

At the other two points $(0,\sqrt{3}/3)$ and $(4, -\sqrt{3}/3)$, the second derivative matrix is not positive or negative semi-definite (the determinate is negative), so we know those points are neither local maxes or mins.

The wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test gives more details on how to use the 2nd derivative test.

Clearly, no global maxima or minima exist. If you consider points of the form $(0,y)$, as $y \to \infty$, $f(0,y) \to \infty$ and as $ y \to -\infty$, $f(0,y) \to -\infty$.

Comment: Hi @David thank you, I found that same answer, just wanted to make sure that I really should use/check those four point. Thanks.